# Is current time within range

Tags: c#, datetime

I know this question has been asked manytimes but mine has a small twist.
There are many different shifts at work and I have two string *shiftStart* and *shiftEnd*.
(example "6:00:00 PM" & "03:00:00 AM" respectively). This represents noon to morning.
I am trying to make a function which tells me if DateTime.Now is within this timeperiod.

**Note:** *the shift can be anything* ... morning to noon, noon to morning, **no** fixed duration (like 8 hours).

```
static bool NowWithinShiftTime("6:00:00 PM", "03:00:00 AM")
```

Following is what I have tried but no matter what I do I cannot seem to find the logic...
Please help me out...

```
static bool NowWithinShiftTime(string shiftStart, string shiftEnd)
    {
        DateTime startDate;
        DateTime endDate;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now; 

        TimeSpan startTime = DateTime.Parse(shiftStart).TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan endTime = DateTime.Parse(shiftEnd).TimeOfDay;

        if (startTime < endTime) // same day
        {
            startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day) + startTime;
            endDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day) + endTime;
        }
        else // next day
        {
            startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.AddDays(-1).Hour) + startTime;
            endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) + endTime;
        }
        if (now >= startDate && now <= endDate)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `now.AddDays(1).Hour` <-- What? Why would you do this?

Comment: @666bytes: You should prefer `startDate = DateTime.Today + startTime`, much shorter and more clear. For tomorrow, `AddDays(1)` as usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could stick with `TimeSpan`:

```
static bool NowWithinShiftTime(string shiftStart, string shiftEnd)
{
    TimeSpan startTime = DateTime.Parse(shiftStart).TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan endTime = DateTime.Parse(shiftEnd).TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    if (startTime < endTime)
        return now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
    else
        return now >= startTime || now <= endTime;
}
```

Comment: @666bytes If possible, it would be even better if the function accepted TimeSpan's instead of strings too instead of doing the parsing.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, make all the *business logic* deal just with time-related types. (Personally I'd use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library with its `LocalTime` type for this work, but...) The parsing can come in the calling code.

The logic is reasonably simple: if the "end time" is actually before the "start time" then just switch the two round and invert the result. After all, you're just dividing the day into "shift time" and "not shift time"... and a shift of (say) 8pm to 3am is "on" whenever a shift of 3am to 8pm is "off".

For example:

```
public bool NowWithinShiftTime(TimeSpan startTimeOfDay, TimeSpan endTimeOfDay)
{
    if (startTimeOfDay > endTimeOfDay)
    {
        return !NowWithinShiftTime(endTimeOfDay, startTimeOfDay);
    }
    TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    return startTimeOfDay <= now && now < endTimeOfDay;
}
```

Notes:

- I've made this deliberately half-closed, as that tends to be appropriate for intervals so that if you have abutting intervals, any given value falls into exactly one. Check exactly what you want, although it'll only be relevant for those two *exact* points in time per day.
- The code is currently hard to test: I'd encourage you to abstract out the idea of "a clock" into an interface, so you can use a fake clock for testing. (Noda Time does this for you, and provides an appropriate `FakeClock`.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're 90% there:

```
static bool NowWithinShiftTime(string shiftStart, string shiftEnd)
{
    DateTime startDate;
    DateTime endDate;
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now; 

    TimeSpan startTime = DateTime.Parse(shiftStart).TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan endTime = DateTime.Parse(shiftEnd).TimeOfDay;

    if (startTime < endTime) // same day
    {
        startDate = DateTime.Today + startTime;
        endDate = DateTime.Today + endTime;
    }
    else // next day
    {
        startDate = DateTime.Today  + startTime;
        endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) + endTime;
    }
    if (now >= startDate && now <= endDate)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's an ideone to show it works: http://ideone.com/rdb867

Comment: This will not work as on reaching 12:00:00 AM the startDate will also become the next date.

Comment: At 12:00 am, the date changes as well so this is a non-issue.

Comment: I tweaked this example a *tiny* bit and got what i needed! THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
static bool NowWithinShiftTime(string shiftStart, string shiftEnd)
{
   DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
   DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(shiftStart);
   DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(shiftEnd);

   if (endDate < startDate)
   {
        endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
   }

   return now >= startDate && now <= endDate;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. `shiftStart` and `shiftEnd` don't have date information, so `now` is always greater than `endDate`.

Comment: @recursive Are you sure? If no date is specified while parsing current date is applied

Comment: @recursive I tested, It works perfectly. Can you show any test case where it fails?

Comment: @recursive: It works because `DateTime.Parse` defaults to the current date when only the time component is specified.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: There is a (highly unlikely but possible) border case that would break your code. If executed at midnight, then `endDate` might be initialized to a different day from `startDate`.

Comment: @recursive Never mind, feel happy that you learnt something today. I'd have felt happy if I was wrong and learnt something from you :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
bool IsWithinTimeRange(DateTime dateToCompare, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    TimeSpan timeToCompare = dateToCompare.TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan start = startDate.TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan end = endDate.TimeOfDay;

    if (start < end)
        return timeToCompare >= start && timeToCompare <= end;
    else
        return !(end < timeToCompare && timeToCompare < start);
}
```